# Division by zero works fine in virtual Destructor

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static int i=1;
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent(){10/i;}
};

class Child: public Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Child(){--i;}
};

int main()
{
    Parent *ptr = new Parent;
    Parent *ptr1 = new Child;
    delete ptr;
    delete ptr1;
    //cout<<10/i;
    return 0;
}
```

Why virtual destructor of the Parent class not providing any runtime error? 
Whereas the commented part of the code throws error when uncommented.

Comment: `cout<<10/i;` also wouldn't work in the virtual destructor. The virtual destructor is completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: this statement (`10/i;`) has no side effects, the compiler presumably optimizes it away

Comment: Note that gcc and clang issue a warning "statement has no effect" for the above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your compiler optimizes the code and removes the useless part, including `10/i` in the base class destructor.

Try with [this](http://codepad.org/4baJq4Yl):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static int i=1;
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent(){int tmp = 10/i; cout << tmp; }
};

class Child: public Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Child(){--i;}
};

int main()
{
    Parent *ptr = new Parent;
    Parent *ptr1 = new Child;
    delete ptr;
    delete ptr1;
    //cout<<10/i;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Undefined behavior is undefined, so anything can happen.

A statement with no side-effects is trivial for the compiler to optimize away, so it doesn't even attempt to execute what's inside the base destructor.

Having it in a `cout` is a different matter - did you try both?

Comment: :( the rich get richer. I wish my imaginary internet points were money.

Comment: @nouney I didn't vote on either answer, but to me, this answer is easier to understand than yours, and that would normally be a reason for me to upvote this answer and not vote (neither up nor down) on yours. It would not be because of your reputation at all.

Comment: @hvd I don't think he was referring to my rep. I'm in the 6 digits, dammit!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You're right, you did nothing wrong, your answer is good and you deserve the upvotes. My comment is not only about this question: It's a general analysis of SO and how the system works.

Comment: @nouney I know your comment wasn't ill-intended. That's why I was joking about it :). But hang in there! The rep will come with persistence and good answers.

Comment: @nouney: Here's a tip: "I guess ..." isn't very convincing. Piotr S. in a comment used "presumably" which already sounds better. And Luchian here starts by stating why assumptions are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the fact that there's no observable behavior, it's fairly easy for the compiler to prove that the `--i` statement is always followed by `10/i`, which in turn means that `--i` cannot be called for `i==1`.

Since `i` is static to the Translation Unit, the optimizer also knows that there's no other code changing `i` from its initial value of `1`.

Thus a modern optimizer can prove that `Child::~Child` isn't called either.

In turn, this means that the fourth line of `main` isn't reachable. This is where things can get really funny. `main` appears to be free of branches, but for the compiler it isn't. `new` may throw, which introduces two branches to this program. And since the "usual" non-exception branch provably can't be executed, the optimizer may conclude that the only reachable branches are the 2 where either `new` statement throws (!)